# AmazonnLinux Docker Image fails to build on simple update

Tags: docker, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows

I am trying to build a Docker image using AmazonLinux image. The build simply fails when performing a simple  `yum update` with the following error:

[image]

For information, I am running `docked` on WSL . On the other side I noticed that can not make a simple curl to the mirror list like `curl -LO https://cdn.amazonlinux.com/al2023/core/mirrors/2023.0.20230315/x86_64/mirror.list`
However the same curl command works on Windows.

My suspicious is that I have an SSL certificate issue on my WSL. Any hints please?